# Trust Region Radius

Tags: numerical-methods, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

Suppose we are in $\mathbb{R}^n$. The trust region subproblem is to find a vector  $\ell$ such we minimize the function
$$f(\ell) = \ell^{T}g + \ell^T B \ell$$
subject to
$$\|\ell\|_2 \leq \Delta$$ for some $\Delta > 0$. Suppose that $B$ is a positive definite matrix. What is
$$\lim_{\Delta \to 0} \frac{\ell}{\|\ell\|_2}?$$

My attempt so far has been the following. Suppose that $\Delta$ is very small. Then
$$f(\ell) = \ell^{T}g + \ell^T B \ell \approx \ell^{T}g.$$
The function approximation should be minimized when $\ell = -\frac{\Delta}{\|g\|_2}\langle g_1,\ldots,g_n\rangle$, so we can use this vector $\ell$ to calculate the limit.

However, I'm not sure how to make my approximation rigorous. I can't see how to use any inequalities since the limit above depends on the point where the minimum will occur, not the minimum itself.

Comment: Do you mean the limit of $f(\ell)/||\ell||$?

Comment: I mean the limit written above in the problem. I expected the vector $\ell$ to be in the direction steepest descent to minimize $f(\ell)$, but I'm not sure how to prove it rigorously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $Δ$ is small enough the minimum will be on the sphere $\|ℓ\|=Δ$. The optimization problem with this equality constraint can be encoded in a Lagrange functional
$$
L(ℓ,\mu)=g^Tℓ+ℓ^TBℓ+\mu(ℓ^Tℓ-Δ^2)
$$
(make that more general with inequality constraints and KKT conditions).

The condition for an extremum point reads then
$$
0=\frac{\partial L}{\partial ℓ}=g+2Bℓ+2\muℓ
$$
or
$$
ℓ=-\frac12(B+\mu I)^{-1}g.
$$
The equation for $\mu$ is then
$$
g^T(B+\mu I)^{-2}g=4Δ^2,\\
\mu^{-2}\left(\|g\|^2-2\mu^{-1}g^TBg+3\mu^{-2}g^TB^2g\mp\ldots\right)=4Δ^2.
$$
As $Δ$ tends to zero, $\mu$ as the other free variable here has to become very large so that $\mu I$ dominates $B$. To normalize the equation, set $\mu^{-1}=\frac{2Δ}{\|g\|}u$, insert and simplify to get
$$
u^2\left(1-4Δ\frac{g^TBg}{\|g\|}u+12Δ^2\frac{g^TB^2g}{\|g\|^2}u^2+\dots\right)=1
$$

In first order, this has the solution $u=1+O(Δ)$, or with the next term $u=1+2Δ\frac{g^TBg}{\|g\|}+O(Δ^2)$, leading to
$$
\mu=\frac{\|g\|}{2Δ}(1+ O(Δ)),
$$
as you also found in your solution (the other sign would approximately maximize the objective function on the sphere). Then, moving the small radius $Δ$ into numerators,
$$
ℓ=-\fracΔ{\|g\|}\left(I+\frac{2Δ}{\|g\|}B\right)^{-1}g.
\implies
\frac{ℓ}{\|ℓ\|}=-\frac{(I+\frac{2Δ}{\|g\|}B)^{-1}g}{\|(I+\frac{2Δ}{\|g\|}B)^{-1}g\|}
$$
which in the limit $Δ\to 0$ indeed converges to $-\frac{g}{\|g\|}$.

Comment: One quick question. When you say "In first order" are you Taylor expanding $g^{T}(B+\mu I)^{-2}g$ around $g = \vec{0}$ and solve?

Comment: Yes, in the sense of expansion in $Δ$, to the first degree terms. One would have to use the formula for $\frac1\mu$ to get terms of comparable magnitude.

Comment: @LutzLehmann sorry for the delayed comment. Could you please provide some guidelines about the Taylor expansion and how $B$ is not included in $\mu$? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: @darkmoor : For small radius $Δ$ the objective function is dominated by the linear term, thus it is not surprising that the quadratic term only occurs in higher order corrections. I made it more specific that where $Δ$ becomes small, $\mu$ has to become large.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am trying to understand your expansion. Which formula is applied?

Comment: Newton's binomial formula $(1+x)^{-2}=1-2x+3x^2-4x^3+...$ with $x=B/\mu$

Comment: @LutzLehmann sorry again. Is it $\mu^2$ instead of $\mu^{-2}$ in the relation with $4\Delta^2$? Also could you please give some more details how $\mu=\frac{\|g\|}{2Δ}(1+ O(Δ))$  is derived? Any directions are highly appreciated.

Comment: No, it is $(ab)^{-2}=a^{-2}b^{-2}$. I inserted another step. $u^2(1-2aΔu+..)=1$ is equivalent by series division to $u^2=1+2aΔu+...$ and taking the series square root to $u=1+aΔu+...$, which solves to $u=1+aΔ+...$

Comment: To compute $u^2=\frac{1}{1-2\alpha\Delta+\dots}$ shall I follow  the division procedure in the section [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series#Multiplication_and_division)? I there another way? Sorry I haven't worked with series before.

Comment: Yes. Series inversion is at the end the solution of a triangular linear system, not exactly rocket science.